# Can I do something when user deletes my app in iOS?

Tags: ios

Can I do something when user deletes the app in iOS? I do not think it is possible, but maybe there are any tricks to call a method of my app or just do something on operating system level?

Comment: what you want to achieve??? may be I can offer my Two cent ;)

Comment: different goals.. for example, redirect user to iTunes link (since I've never seen that). My partner said he did see that, so I decided to make it clear

Comment: well, if someone is interested - I figured out that on older iOS (4.2 or so) there was a redirecting to app's iTunes page by iOS itself when deleting an app. However, you could not do anything by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.. You cannot catch the Application Delete event..!!